# abstract compareTo method not being overrided

Tags: java, compiler-errors, compareto

When compiling the code below, I get the following error:

> PersonalInformation is not abstract and does not override abstract
>   method compareTo(Object) in Comparable

I assume that means I have a problem with my `compareTo` method. But everything seems to be all right. Anyone have a suggestion?

```
import java.util.*;
public class PersonalInformation implements Comparable
{
private String givenName;
private String middleInitial;
private String surname;
private String gender;
private String emailAddress;
private String nationalId;
private String telephoneNum;
private String birthday;

public PersonalInformation(String gN, String mI, 
        String sur, String gen, String eMa, String natId,
        String teleNum, String birthd)

{
        givenName = gN;
        middleInitial = mI;
        surname = sur;
        gender = gen;
        emailAddress = eMa;
        nationalId = natId;
        telephoneNum = teleNum;
        birthday = birthd;


}


public int compareTo(PersonalInformation pi)
{
 return (this.gender).compareTo(pi.gender);
}

}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Do this:

```
public int compareTo(Object pi) {
    return ((PersonalInformation )(this.gender)).compareTo(((PersonalInformation ) pi).gender);
}
```

or better

```
public class PersonalInformation implements Comparable<PersonalInformation>
```

If you implement the `Comparable` Interface you have to implement it either for all Objects using the first method or type your class the second way.

Answer (score 6):

#### See juergen d's answer, much better.

You're overloading the method:

```
public int compareTo(PersonalInformation pi)
{
    return (this.gender).compareTo(pi.gender);
}
```

instead of overriding it:

```
public int compareTo(Object pi)
```

It could be something like:

```
public int compareTo(Object pi)
{
    if ( ! pi instanceof PersonalInformation )
        return false;
    return (this.gender).compareTo( (PersonalInformation)pi.gender );
}
```

Comment: I think it's called overloading, not overriding.

Answer (score 6):

You need to implement `Comparable<PersonalInformation>` rather than `Comparable` for your class to compile and work.

If you are implementing Comparable, the expected method signature is `compareTo(Object o)` which is missing in your class and hence the error.